# Moving PostgreSQL data directory from Solaris to Linux

Tags: linux, postgresql, solaris, database-migration

I'm trying to find information if it is possible to:

1. Stop PostgreSQL server.
2. Copy entire data directory to a different server (same PostgreSQL version, but different OS: Solaris 64bit Intel to Linux (CentOS) 64 bit Intel.
3. Start PostgreSQL server and point the apps to the new server.

P.S. I'm aware about other ways of migrating to a different OS.

Comment: I did the test with a simple db and simple table and this approach worked.

Answer (score 0):

PostgreSQL requires that data type sizes and endianness be the same for the datadir to be compatible.

PostgreSQL must also be compiled with the same options for integer datetimes, large file support, segment size, block size, WAL segment size and WAL block size. Except for integer datetimes, which are sometimes turned off for backward compatibility with old datadirs, these parameters are rarely changed.

So long as both hosts are x64 and use the same type sizes (i.e. they're both [LP64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit_computing#64-bit_data_models) architectures), both are little-endian, both share the same representations of 32- and 64-bit floating point values, and both are compiled with the same options you should be fine.

Of course, you're making a backup first anyway, right?

Comment: >> Of course, you're making a backup first anyway, right?

Comment: Yes and a lot of testing.